# How to aggregate data in google sheets this (shown in example) way

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data set in google sheets which looks like this.

| Date | Name | Quality | Speech | Politeness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 4/7/2023 | James | 90 | 95 | 85 |
| 4/7/2023 | James | 100 | 100 | 99 |
| 4/7/2023 | Bill | 50 | 60 | 55 |
| 4/7/2023 | Bill | 20 | 30 | 25 |
| 5/17/2023 | James | 61 | 60 | 70 |
| 5/17/2023 | Bill | 75 | 70 | 72 |
| 5/17/2023 | Bill | 15 | 10 | 12 |

I need to count average scores per person per month, so the output would look exactly like this, so months would be column names. Person names and features would be indexes. This is what I need:

|  |  | Year 2023 |  |  |  | Year 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | April | May | So on ... |  |  |
| Bill |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Quality | 35 | 45 |  |  |  |
|  | Speech | 45 | 40 |  |  |  |
|  | Politeness | 40 | 42 |  |  |  |
| James |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Quality | 95 | 61 |  |  |  |
|  | Speech | 97.5 | 60 |  |  |  |
|  | Politeness | 92 | 70 |  |  |  |

The best shot was with formula:

=QUERY(test_1!A:E, "select B, A, AVG(C), AVG(D), AVG(E) group by B, A label AVG(C) 'Quality', AVG(D) 'Speech', AVG(E) 'Politeness'")

| Name | Date | Quality | Speech | Politeness |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Bill | 4/7/2023 | 35 | 45 | 40 |  |  |
| Bill | 5/17/2023 | 45 | 40 | 42 |  |  |
| James | 4/7/2023 | 95 | 97.5 | 92 |  |  |
| James | 5/17/2023 | 61 | 60 | 70 |  |  |

The result is somewhat close, but not exactly what I want.

So the questions are:

1. What is best way to get desired result, I'm limited with google sheets only, so no pandas.
2. What I should change in my formula to get desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(row,let(b,B2:B,z,tocol(C1:E1),y,{"",""},{y;reduce(y,unique(tocol(b,1)),lambda(a,c,{a;{c,if(,,)};{wrapcols(,counta(z),),z}}))}),
     col,let(x,A2:A,yr,unique(index(year(tocol(x,1)))),reduce(torow(,1),yr,lambda(a,c,hstack(a,let(Σ,torow(unique(filter(text(x,"mmm"),year(x)=c))),if(counta(Σ)=1,{c;Σ},{{c,wraprows(,counta(Σ)-1,)};Σ})))))),
     Σ,  scan(,index(col,1,),lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),Λ,scan(,query(index(row,,1),"offset 2"),lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),
         {row,{col;makearray(counta(Λ),counta(Σ),lambda(r,c,ifna(average(filter(filter(A:E,A1:E1=index(query(index(row,,2),"offset 2"),r)),year(A:A)=index(Σ,,c),text(A:A,"mmm")=index(index(col,2,),,c),B:B=index(Λ,r))))))}})
```

- *It auto-expands to `right` and `downwards` as new data is added to source point `A:E`*

[image]

**`formula breakup`**

*formula in `Cell_G1`(refer screenshot) is 2 columns wide & expands auto-downwards*

```js
=let(b,B2:B,z,tocol(C1:E1),y,{"",""},{y;reduce(y,unique(tocol(b,1)),lambda(a,c,{a;{c,if(,,)};{wrapcols(,counta(z),),z}}))})
```

*formula in `Cell_I1` is 2 rows length & expands to right*

```js
=let(x,A2:A,yr,unique(index(year(tocol(x,1)))),reduce(torow(,1),yr,lambda(a,c,hstack(a,let(Σ,torow(unique(filter(text(x,"mmm"),year(x)=c))),if(counta(Σ)=1,{c;Σ},{{c,wraprows(,counta(Σ)-1,)};Σ}))))))
```

*formula in `Cell_I3` takes help of above 2 variations & then auto-expands to right n' downside*

```js
=let(Σ,scan(,I1:1,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),Λ,scan(,G3:G,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),makearray(counta(Λ),counta(Σ),lambda(r,c,ifna(average(filter(filter(A:E,A1:E1=index(H3:H,r)),year(A:A)=index(Σ,,c),text(A:A,"mmm")=index(I2:2,,c),B:B=index(Λ,r)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: That totally works, thanks! Looks like kinda magic. Could you break down this formula by pieces - which part is for what.

Comment: formula breakup into 3 pieces added to answer for easy of using...

Comment: That's clear. One more question popped up. How to avoid error if sometimes "NA" (string) values appear in cells? How to ignore them in this given formula?

Comment: Please share a test sheet recreating this scenario & I can check it out.